# "Failed to create CUDA context (Illegal address)"

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, gpu

I get this error when trying to render in cycles with CUDA and OPTIX with GPU Compute. I did not have this error earlier. This is both in the 3.4 and 3.5 builds. This problem occurs on all driver versions I have tried. I am running a GTX 1060 Ti.

Comment: I think I've experienced a similar bug in the past. Here's how I would fix it. Add a new empty scene to your project. Add a camera and render a frame. Go back to your main scene and try re-rendering.